# What is the maximum size of a cookie, and how many can be stored in a browser for each web site?

Tags: cookies

I am learning about cookies, and I wonder about browser support when writing web applications that rely on cookies to store state.

- For each domain/web site, how many cookies may be sent to a browser, and of what size?
- If multiple cookies are sent and stored, does that affect performance?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Firstly, I suggest you don't worry about this issue. There is AMPLE room to serialize tons of identifiers to.

Secondly it's not stored by `web-server` but by `web-domain` — e.g., `www.google.com` and not the 100's of different physical servers that serve the Google domain.

Thirdly if you do have to worry know that there are **two possible cookie headers**. The sizes of these cookie headers are determined by the browser software limits.

**Design Discussion**

What you don't want to use the cookie header for is sending details about a client's session. E.g., don't try to stuff the email a client is typing into a cookie if you are building an email front-end. Instead you would send the client a cookie that represents his identity+session: you store all sessions data against this identity.  You can store tens of identifiers (4–16 bytes) per cookie header and no one needs more than say 4 of these. The  cookies data (as an integer) tends to be encoded to [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) which increases the byte-count.

**Performance**

Your browser sends a plethora of headers to a web-server. The cookie is just another 100-1000 bytes (mostly closer to 100). At both extremes it takes only a fraction of time to send these to the web-server — when placed into context of course. You should keep in mind that the web is built on text based protocols.

Comment: The cookie header is not only sent to request the html, but for all resources that is loaded from the same domain. So if a lot of data is stored in cookies, it will affect performance quite a bit. http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2007/03/01/performance-research-part-3/

Comment: well yes, I am evidently not suggesting storing the combined works of Shakespeare in the cookie. People have the ability to exercise common sense when reading informal answers on stack overflow.

Comment: Also that analysis is completely useless in the general case. I have written high performance custom GUID based cookie generation code in my research and it adds NO extra latency. So you really need to learn how to interpret research based results and learn how to place them in context, instead of shoehorning the results which don't apply into this answer. To quote Saadi "Nothing is so good for an ignorant man as silence; and if he was sensible of this he would not be ignorant."

Comment: Is it ok if I keep delete the cookie and again drop it...my app is such that I have to do this quite a few times..?

Answer (score 51):

No more than 50 cookies per domain, with a maximum of 4 KB per cookie (or even 4 KB in total, see [Iain's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6963585/20980)). On IE 6 it used to be 20 cookies per domain.

Generally it's recommended to preserve state on the server, and use cookies only for session tracking. They're sent along with every request, so they form an unnecessary overhead if the purpose is to keep session state around.

If you do want to keep state on the client, and you can use JavaScript to do it, there are options. Use the assorted storage API's directly or find a wrapper library that abstracts away the details.

Client-side storage options:

- [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage): Firefox 2+, Chrome 4+, Safari 4+, Internet Explorer 8+. 5 MB per domain without user confirmation (but be aware that it is stored as UTF-16 so you may use two bytes per character).
- [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/IndexedDB): Firefox 4+, Chrome 11+, Safari 10+, Internet Explorer 10+. 5 MB per domain without user confirmation, much more after confirmation (highly browser specific, check your browser for details).

Deprecated storage options:

- Flash 8 persistent storage: any browser with Flash 8+. 100 KB, more with user permission. Deprecated because Flash itself is deprecated.
- [userData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531424(VS.85).aspx): Internet Explorer 5.5+. 64 KB per domain in the restricted zone, 128 KB per domain in the internet zone. Replaced by localStorage.
- [Web SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_SQL_Database): Chrome & Safari only, it will never make it to other browsers because it was [not possible to standardize it](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/220254/why-is-web-sql-database-deprecated).

So, generally for client-side storage it depends on the use case:

- For session id tracking or for a few KB, use cookies.
- Up to 2 MB, localstorage delivers a solution across all common browsers.
- 2 MB and up, use IndexedDB (look for a good wrapper library).

Comment: RFC 2109 specifies minimum 20 cookies pr domain. Each 4kB. But I've read that IE6 only have 4kB for all 20 of them. So just 4kB in total!

Comment: @gregers: don't know (care) about IE6. But on IE7/8 it's definitely 4KB for each cookie and NOT 4KB for all cookies.

Comment: @Marco Demaio: Happy to be corrected, however my test script reports IE7 4KB limit, IE8 10KB limit for all cookies. See http://myownplayground.atspace.com/cookietest.html

Comment: @Iain: +1 you seem to be totally right. I tested just couple of 4KB cookies on IE8 and saw they were working so I thought I could write more. You should add an answer here with your results and a link to your great test page.

Comment: @Marco Demaio: That is a relief :) I thought I might have been wrong. I have posted an answer

Comment: Is it ok if I keep delete the cookie and again drop it...my app is such that I have to do this quite a few times..?

Comment: There is an msdn faq about cookie limits: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/08/20/wininet-ie-cookie-internals-faq.aspx?PageIndex=5

Answer (score 25):

**Cookie Size Limits**

If you want to support most browsers, then do not exceed **50 cookies per domain**, and **4093 bytes per domain**. That is, the size of all cookies should not exceed 4093 bytes.

**Performance Thoughts**

Cookies are sent on every request for a domain, this includes images. For arguments sake, let's say you have 30 resources on your website, and have 4093 bytes of cookies. That means the user is uploading 122Kb of data. So if I have a 1Mbit upload connection, that will take at least 1 second.

If you want to see the cookie test page I created, or read more about it, check out [Browser Cookie Limits](http://browsercookielimits.iain.guru/).

Comment: This was a great find. It's pretty much not just an IE thing on that cookie size restriction.

Answer (score 6):

If you are concerned about performance decreases due to large cookies being sent on each server request, a good idea might be to place all your static files (images, CSS, etc.) into a subdomain of your site, like `http://static.yourdomain.com`.

In this way, whenever your site on `www.yourdomain.com`  asks for a static file,like an image, the browser won't send the cookie along with the HTTP request anymore.

Source: http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#cookie_free

Answer (score 4):

Different browswers have different size limites on cookies. Here is the information for [IE](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306070). [Here](http://www.ghacks.net/2008/08/16/browser-cookie-limits/) is a page that lists several browsers.

Cookies are not saved on a server basis but on a *domain* basis (a server may host many domains or the opposite a server farm may be serving a single domain).

In general, I would avoid saving lots of information in cookies, as the data gets sent to and from the browser on every request. As you suggest in your question, this can have a effect on performance.

Usually one stores small amounts of data in the cookie, mostly used to identify the user/session so more data can be picked up from a database or another resource local to the web server.

Comment: Many agree about not making the cookies too large (or avoid them whenever possible, like for static content): http://yuiblog.com/blog/2007/03/01/performance-research-part-3/ But still Ruby on Rails stores the whole session in a cookie by default: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#session-storage

Answer (score 3):

If you're programming a web site, it's a good idea not to store too much in a cookie, because that cookie gets send to the server every time the user requests a page from your site.  A far better solution is to just store a unique id in the cookie, and let the server pull up the required information from a database or file store based on that unique id.  Unfortunately that solution leads to people worrying about what you're tracking about them, so you might want to have a "cookie policy" expressed somewhere on your site talking about why you're placing a cookie on their browser and what you do and don't track about them.

Answer (score 3):

**4096 bytes**
The real problem, however, comes when you try and set cookies with a large size. The standards state that a browser must support a minimum of 4096 bytes per cookie. IE6 doesn't do this. Instead, it seems to have a maximum size of 4096 bytes for all cookies from a domain.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a really good site on cookie limits and lets you test your browser:

http://browsercookielimits.iain.guru/

Answer (score 0):

**CDN Comes to Rescue.**

You can offload your static content to a CDN or a file storage service like Amazon S3, keeping the static file requests cookie-free should be easy as long as you haven’t set up a CNAME record on a subdomain that receives cookies from your top-level domain.

This [Blog Post](http://www.ravelrumba.com/blog/static-cookieless-domain/) is a good read for on Serving Static Content from a Cookieless Domain and how can we adopt this best practice to boost our performance in the client side.