# Using cookie to store PageID of webpage (which changes often) - is this suitable?

Tags: asp.net, cookies, html

For the first time, I need to save a `PageID` variable when the user visits the asp.net webpage. Every time the user selects a new webpage, the `PageID` variable will be updated.

I am not allowed to use session variables at this stage - specifications does not allow it.

My question : I've only used cookies before when the values don't get changed - e.g. UserID or ApplicationID. For the first time now I will use it for a value that gets changed often.
Is this suitable?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you keep the total size of the cookie relative small the changing of a variable on the cookie on every page load is not an issue.

About the cookie size : http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#cookie_size

And about the size limit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6963585/159270