# Store a complete array in a cookie

Tags: php, arrays, cookies

I have the following array:

> Array ( [0] => 1 
>             [1] => 1 
>             [2] => 3 
>             [3] => 6 )

and I would like to store it in a cookie.  This is the code I tried:

```
$cart_array = Array ( [0] => 1 
          [1] => 1 
          [2] => 3 
          [3] => 6 );

setcookie('cart_array',$cart_array,time()+3600);
```

when I display the contents of the cookie using `print_r($_Cookie)`, this is what I get:

> Array ( [cart] => Array ( [0] => 6 [id] => 2 ) [_ga] => GA1.1.499529088.1424453778 [PHPSESSID] => aj8p5l5ph77n04tab50i83ie34 )

instead of the array I inserted to cookie. Please assist

Comment: Why not store it in a session instead? From the [PHPSESSID] key it looks like you're using them.

Comment: I need to use cookies for this project.  I am comfortable with sessions, but just starting to get into cookies

Comment: Instead of `serialize` you might look at `json_encode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for serialize:

```
<?php
$a = array(1 => 'a', 2 => 'b', 3 => 'c');
$b = serialize($a);
var_dump($b); ////Returns this string(42) "a:3:{i:1;s:1:"a";i:2;s:1:"b";i:3;s:1:"c";}"
$c = unserialize($b);
print_r($c); //Return the same thing as $a
```

Try out this code, you use serialize to convert an array to string and then you can easily store it. Then, you unserialize to have the array back !

Doc: http://php.net/manual/fr/function.serialize.php

Answer (score 0):

Cookies does not work with arrays - they are only strings on the local computer. With

```
$res = serialize($arr);
```

you can convert an array to a string. (Convert it back with *unserialize($arr)*.)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
setcookie('cart_array',implode('|',$cart_array),time()+3600);
```

Use this to read cookie back to array:

```
$cart_array = explode('|',$_COOKIE['cart_array'])
```

Although I don't think its really necessary to do that. but, just answering your question.

And please be careful to the total length of the Cookie [What is the maximum size of a cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093793/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-a-cookie-and-how-many-can-be-stored-in-a-browser-fo)

Answer (score 0):

Use `serialize()`

```
setcookie('cart_array',serialize($cart_array),time()+3600);

$cart_array = unserialize($_COOKIE['cart_array']);
```

Depending on special characters that may arise (not likely, but good to know if you do) you may also need `urlencode()`:

```
setcookie('cart_array',urlencode(serialize($cart_array))),time()+3600);


$cart_array = unserialize(urldecone($_COOKIE['cart_array']));
```