# What happens if I exceed the limit of maximum cookies

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

As far as I read there is are two limits on the number of cookies :

- 20 cookies per unique host or domain name
- a total of 300 cookies

What does happen if I exceed one of these limits ?

Comment: You should eat some of them, don't hoard too many cookies at once.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short Answer:**

1. If you exceed the limits per host/domain, the cookies simply **won't be saved**.
2. If you exceed the total number of cookies, Your browser will alert you that the [maximum number of cookies has been reached](https://cait.calarts.edu/hc/en-us/articles/217055138-Error-Maximum-Number-of-Cookie-Values-Reached)

Note that your question states that the max number of cookies per host is 20 and the total allowed is 300. However, this is not completely true. The number of maximum cookies is **highly dependent** on the Browser. For example,

- Chrome 9 allowed 180 cookies per domain
- Firefox 3.6.3 allowed 50 cookies per domain

As far as the [RFC spec](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt) goes, the minimum requirements are:

- *at least* 300 cookies
- *at least* 4096 bytes per cookie
- *at least* 20 cookies
  per unique host or domain name

This [resource](http://browsercookielimits.iain.guru/) can help you test browser cookie limits. Also this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093793/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-a-cookie-and-how-many-can-be-stored-in-a-browser-fo) will shed some light on the design and performance aspect.

*References*: [Cookie Limit per domain](https://www.thoughtco.com/cookie-limit-per-domain-3466809), [Browser Cookie Restrictions](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2008/05/17/browser-cookie-restrictions/)

Comment: what do you mean by "at least 300 cookies" but " Chrome 9 allowed 180 cookies per domain
Firefox 3.6.3 allowed 50 cookies per domain
"  ?

Comment: it means that according to the RFC specs (check the link in the post), the requirements are that browsers support at least 300 cookies. But browsers are **not obliged** to comply.

Comment: The resource to help test browser cookie limits is down. Maybe [this page](http://browsercookielimits.iain.guru/) does something similar.

Comment: Yes you're right. I updated the answer with the link you provided. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I tried adding lots of cookies with a quick loop (100 at a time) both Chrome 69.0.3497 and FireFox 62.0.3 remove the older cookies and store the new ones.